# Add facebook comments inside fancybox with photo

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, facebook-comments

how to add facebook comments in a fancybox? in my HTML i've this:

```
<a  class="fb" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Laurea" href="http://mediablog.cadenadial.com/atrevete/files/2012/10/cocheespa%C3%B1a.jpg">
<img  src="http://mediablog.cadenadial.com/atrevete/files/2012/10/cocheespa%C3%B1a.jpg" alt=""   width="19%"/></a>
```

then in other file called js.js I've a fancybox function:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));



    $(".fb")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        padding: 0,    
        afterShow : function(){
        var myContent = '<div id="myContent">
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:210px; height:30px;" allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=' + this.href + '&permalink=1"  scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width="600" height="600"" allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
  </div>';
 $(".fancybox-wrap").append(myContent);}
 });
```

How do  I to show the comments in a fancybox? thx

Comment: do you mean this http://jsfiddle.net/dF4tT/4/show/light/ ?

Comment: Hi JFK, 
Maybe I have formulated my question wrong.
I want to know if when you clik on a picture with fancybox may appear the photo and in the photo beside or below put the social plugin Facebook comments, thanx again

Comment: in the javascript file I have this:

$(".fb")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        padding: 0,

Comment: afterShow : function(){
        var myContent = '<div id="myContent"><iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:210px; height:30px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=' + this.href + '&permalink=1" scrolling="yes" overflow:hidden; width:130px; height:30px;" allowTransparency="false"></iframe> </div>';

Comment: $(".fancybox-wrap").append(myContent);

But not displayed correctly

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that it does not show the comment plugin because the site is already parsed and it´s added dynamically. Try the following right after the "append" function:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

So, you either just use `FB.XFBML.parse();` to parse the whole document (again), or you use `FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('foo'));` to parse a specific element with a specific id. Should also work for subitems.

Also, use the correct plugin code for it, not the iframe-version:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: Sorry i'm spanish and don't speak english well.
I should put the FB.XFBML.parse() after $(".fancybox-wrap").append(myContent);?? this?

$(".fb")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        padding: 0,    
        afterShow : function(){
        var myContent = '<div id="myContent">  </div>';
 FB.XFBML.parse();
 $(".fancybox-wrap").append(myContent);

}       
    });???

thanks very much

Comment: AFTER the append, not before it:
$(".fancybox-wrap").append(myContent);
FB.XFBML.parse();

Comment: thanks Luschn , the photo is displayed but still missing beneath the comment

Comment: can you post the link? i´d like to test it

Comment: i meant a link to the real site. it does not really work in jsfiddle, fancybox would also need to be included and so on. but i can tell you this already: there is no official iframe version of the like button or comment plugin, at least not anymore. better generate a new code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: could you tell me if you think I should do thus to leave the messages?

Comment: if there is no real url, then that might be the problem: facebook needs to be able to access the page with the social plugins > it needs to be public

Comment: thanks, but even so it could make the comments appear beside photo as in facebook within a fancybox?

Comment: sure, after all a fancybox overlay is just a simple html-container. try it on a real server, and not on your local apache...

Comment: hm...now that you mention it...is there even a fancybox-wrap container? does fancybox create it automatically? i dunno...it could also be a problem, maybe there is just no container with that class. would lead to a error in the browser console though.

Comment: yes yes that's a wrap,
I've got to show the photo and below the Facebook social plugin, but I can not change the dimesion, is small